# How to make WSCoachMarksView walkthrough only run the first time user opens app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I'm using [WSCoachMarksView](https://github.com/workshirt/WSCoachMarksView) to give my users a walkthrough the first time they open up the app, and I obviously only want this to run that first time, and never again after that. I followed the instructions in the documentation that tells you to put the respective code that I have in `viewDidAppear`so that it only runs once, but it doesn't seem to work.

It still runs through the walkthrough every time the app is open. Is there anything I'm not doing properly to detect the app running previously and setting the BOOL so that it doesn't run again?

**SearchViewController.m:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Setup coach marks
    NSArray *coachMarks = @[
                            @{
                                @"rect": [NSValue valueWithCGRect:(CGRect){{50,168},{220,45}}],
                                @"caption": @"Just browsing? We'll only notify you periodically of new matches. Need it soon? We'll notify you more frequently, and match you with items that are closer to you."
                                },
                            ];

    self.coachMarksView = [[WSCoachMarksView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tabBarController.view.bounds coachMarks:coachMarks];
    [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:self.coachMarksView];
    self.coachMarksView.animationDuration = 0.5f;
    self.coachMarksView.enableContinueLabel = YES;

    [self.coachMarksView start];
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // Show coach marks
    BOOL coachMarksShown = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"WSCoachMarksShown"];
    if (coachMarksShown == NO) {
        // Don't show again
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"WSCoachMarksShown"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        // Show coach marks
        [self.coachMarksView start];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in viewDidLoad you always start your intro, regardless of what you've set in NSUserDefaults. The check in viewDidAppear is correct, but it's already playing at that time